Private network - can't access partion from desktop
I have two computers relative to my query.
My laptop is setup to dual boot Ubuntu or Windows 11. Most of the time I use Ubuntu which is used as a Plex server. On the laptop I have an NTFS partition that has my media as shown in Disks:

Now for my desktop. I have shared my media on both Ubuntu and Windows, //192.168.1.5/PlexMovies. My fstab mounts the laptop NTFS partition /dev/sda5 and works fine for Plex.
What I cannot do is access this partition from my desktop when Ubuntu is running on the laptop. If I boot the laptop into Windows, I can access the media partition. Is there a fix for this?

I've been able to implement a workaround to access the Laptop NTFS partition.
I setup and got running, after a few failures, Remote Desktop to connect with Ubuntu on my laptop.
With RDT, I can switch between Ubuntu and Windows 11 on my desktop and add and view files. I'm still interested in way to do this more efficiently.

Well I "found" the easy way :-()
You can see above that the partition is //192.168.1.5/ from the shot above, however when I'm logged onto Ubuntu the IP is 192.168.1.71!
Good news it's simple now and I have RMD setup too.
